# ProgressBar in android webview not stop spinning

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

i'm creating a android webview app. Im facing a problem with progress bar. The progress bar is completely and fully implemented and keeps spinning. but it doesn't stop spinning even after the page loads completely. what should i do?

main activity layout::::

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

mainActivity.java:::

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
WebView web;
ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://google.com");
    web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());   }

public class webclient extends WebViewClient   {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

Where is the error here? please help me im also having problem with adview. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341238/android-adview-getting-error)

Comment: http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-webview-loading-url-with.html

Answer (score 1):

You've created a custom WebViewClient class but you aren't using it.

Change `web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());`

to `web.setWebViewClient(new webclient());`

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. now could you please help me with that adview error also. will you? Is there a way to hide page not available page and show a message?

Answer (score 1):

Change these two methods.

@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
```

progressBar.dismiss();

}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onPageFinished(view, url);
```

}

Change web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

to web.setWebViewClient(new webclient());

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. other than that progressBar.dismiss(); instead i placed the old code at onPageFinished. thanks anyway. please help me with that adview error also. will you? Is there a way to hide page not available page and show a message?

Comment: please let tick the answer of mine and vote up my answer.
i will answer your question at that post.

Comment: vote up requires 15 reputation. sorry. 100Ticks here bro :)

help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341238/android-adview-getting-error

Comment: its not at all working bro :( i'm going mad. now when i closed eclipse and opened. it shows a build path error

Comment: send me the exceptions.

Comment: how to send exceptions? email: akill.here@gmail.com

Comment: Everything working fine. But now I noted that the progress bar is shown only in the start page. It is not visible in other pages or even when a link is clicked. What should I do?